# Error inflating android.support.v7.widget.CardView

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-cardview

Before diving into the code, I do want to mention that Android Studio says ***The following class couldn't be found: android.support.v7.widget.CardView***, even though I have it downloaded it.(Images below)

(*Error saying CardView not found, though no download option is found.)* [image: Error saying CardView not found, though no download option is found.]

Here's the code for the activity having the error.

*ContactsActivity.kt*

(contactView is the RecyclerView)

```kotlin
package com.smartherd.msgshareapp

import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.smartherd.msgshareapp.models.Contact
import com.smartherd.msgshareapp.models.adapters.ContactAdapter
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_contacts.*

class ContactsActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        val layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
        layoutManager.orientation = LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL

        contactsView.layoutManager = layoutManager  // Oops! contactsView is NULL!

        contactsView.adapter = ContactAdapter(this, Contact.allContacts)
    }
}
```

Here's *activity_contact.xml*

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dp">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/contactsView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scrollbars="vertical" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Contact class

```kotlin
package com.smartherd.msgshareapp.models

import org.json.JSONArray
import org.json.JSONObject
import java.io.File

data class Contact(val name: String, val phone: String, val email: String) {
    companion object {

       val allContacts: List<Contact>
        get() {
            val json = JSONObject(File("contacts.json").readText()).getJSONArray("contacts")
            // Looks like {"contacts": [{"name": ..., "email": ..., "phone": ...}, ...]}

            val contacts = mutableListOf<Contact>()

            var i = 0

            while (i < json.length()) {
                val name = json.getJSONObject(i).getString("name")
                val phone = json.getJSONObject(i).getString("phone")
                val email = json.getJSONObject(i).getString("email")

                contacts.add(Contact(name, phone, email))

                ++i
            }

            return contacts
        }

    }
}
```

And the Contact Adapter class (ContactAdapter.kt)

```kotlin
package com.smartherd.msgshareapp.models.adapters

import android.content.Context
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.smartherd.msgshareapp.R
import com.smartherd.msgshareapp.models.Contact
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.card_contact.view.*

class ContactAdapter(val context: Context, val contacts: List<Contact>) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<ContactAdapter.ContactHolder>() {

    inner class ContactHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        fun initialize(contact: Contact) {
            itemView.contactName.text = "${contact.name}\n${contact.email}"
            // itemView.contactImage is not set yet.
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ContactHolder =
        ContactHolder(
            LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.card_contact, parent, false)
        )

    override fun getItemCount(): Int = contacts.size

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ContactHolder, position: Int) = holder.initialize(contacts[position])
}
```

Comment: In the first screenshot it looks like you've tried to add the cardview dependency in the project-level `build.gradle`. It should go in `app/build.gradle` instead.

Comment: Since I have changed the question after this comment, I want to clarify that I have cut and pasted that line into app/build.gradle and the error still persists as if nothing changed. Although the build is now successful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first add **`setContentView();`**

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main) //missing
    val recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.contactsView) as RecyclerView
```

Use Exact version **`App Level`** `build.gradle`

```
 dependencies {

       implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
       implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
      }
```

### FYI

You are using very old versions. If you want to use latest then libraries will not work unless you make the following changes in your app:

- Upgrade compileSdkVersion to 28 or later.
- Update your app to use Jetpack (AndroidX).

AndroidX replaces the original support library APIs with packages in the androidx namespace. Read official guideline about [**`AndroidX Overview`**](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx).

Your **`Cardview`** & **`recyclerview`** will

```
 implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
 implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0'
```

Comment: Thanks, but now the error changes to "cannot inflate android.support.v7.widget.CardView". Would this go away if I build a fresh new project with whatever you told?

Comment: @VivekYadav you should add app level build.gradle section. under `dependencies`

Comment: Did that, build is successful. The error still persists.

Comment: @VivekYadav did you declare RecyclerView in `onCreate`?

Comment: I didn't declare it in there, I just used it directly with the synthetic.main thingy

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212273/discussion-between-vivek-yadav-and-intellij-amiya).

Answer (score 1):

Ok, with the help of @IntellijAmiya in the chat, I figured it's basically because I have used "android.support.v7.widget.CardView" when I should have used the androidX alternative in app/build.gradle . Also, in the XML file designing the cards, I have not used the androidX alternative. Doing so fixed it.